# How do I get pics downloaded to PC

Tags: onedrive, photos, cloud-storage

How do I get my photos to go from my One drive to PC in nice neat folders that I keep everything in?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sync-files-with-the-onedrive-sync-client-in-windows-615391c4-2bd3-4aae-a42a-858262e42a49

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OneDrive sync client in PC to sync photos in OneDrive. The OneDrive desktop client is generally installed with Windows 10 or Office 2016 by default.

If you don't have Windows 10 or Office 2016, install the Windows version of the new OneDrive sync client below:
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=844652